# Error while saving two consecutive times the same mail

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, mapi, outlook-2013

While trying to use the `UserProperties` of a `MailItem` in Outlook to add some custom information, I've found the problem that a mail cannot be saved two consecutive times without raising the exception

> The operation cannot be performed because the message has been
>   changed.

I've been researching it and some people have suggested that it can be related to not releasing the COM objects properly, so I moved the code to a new AddIn, tested it there making sure that all the objects were properly released and the exception was still there. This led me to think that the problem is related with the synchronization with IMAP because I'm using a gmail account to test the AddIn. But if that's the case, what can I do to avoid getting this exception? Here is my code:

> NOTE: The code is meant to be executed every time the user clicks a button with a mail selected. The first time the
>   `UserProperty` is set to `foo` and the second time, since it's the same
>   mail and it has the property named `custom property`, it changes the value to
>   `bar`.
>   The exception is raised when performing the `mail.Save()` the second time for the same mail.

```
    Explorer explorer = null;
    Selection selection = null;
    MailItem mail = null;
    UserProperties props = null;
    UserProperty prop = null;

    try
    {
        app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        explorer = app.ActiveExplorer();
        selection = explorer.Selection;            
        mail = selection[1] as MailItem;

        string customProperty = "Custom property";
        props = mail.UserProperties;
        prop = props.Find(customProperty);
        if (prop == null)
        {
           prop = props.Add(customProperty, OlUserPropertyType.olText);
           prop.Value = "foo";
           Debug.WriteLine("added property: foo");
        }
        else
        {
           prop.Value = "bar";                            
           Debug.WriteLine("change property: bar");
        }

        mail.Save();

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (prop != null && Marshal.IsComObject(prop))
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(prop);

        if (props != null && Marshal.IsComObject(props))
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(props);

        if (mail != null && Marshal.IsComObject(mail))
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);

        if (selection != null && Marshal.IsComObject(selection))
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selection);

        if (explorer != null && Marshal.IsComObject(explorer))
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(explorer);       
    }
```

I've tried waiting some time before saving the mail the second time but time doesn't seem to matter. Any suggestion?

> NOTE2: The code works without problem when the mail is placed in a
>   local folder.
>
> NOTE3: Disabling the Outlook `reading pane`, allows me to save the
>   mail one more time, raises the exception the third time, but saves it
>   correctly if I try it a fourth time

Comment: Youre only changing one property here Im guessing its how you've called it, its probably complaining because if you have MailItem1 and you go ahead and change it but then go to change something else, the original MailItem1 is no longer current

Comment: The code is meant to be executed two times. The first time the user property is set to "foo" and the second time, since it's the same mail and has the property "custom property" it changes the value to "bar". I'll add this to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: try closing the mailitem and setting them to actual null..

Comment: Sadly, it makes no difference.

Comment: darn - doing so has always solved so many of these kinds of issues.

Comment: I've checked that having the mail in a local folder allows me to save it as many times as I want, which confirms it is related with the IMAP synchronization.

Comment: have you tried triggering the send and receive and waiting for it to complete after the update?

Comment: Yes and I still get the exception...

Comment: that kinda rules out the sync then

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the code on the main thread only? Do you run secondary threads?

In the code, you may check for a property value and its value. If the value equals to the value you need to set up, there is no need to assign the same value. In that case, you may set a flag that no changes were performed on the item and cancel the `Save` call.

```
    bool skipSave = false;
    if (prop == null)
    {
       prop = props.Add(customProperty, OlUserPropertyType.olText);
       prop.Value = "foo";
       Debug.WriteLine("added property: foo");
    }
    else
    {
       if(prop.Value != "bar")
       {
          prop.Value = "bar";
          Debug.WriteLine("change property: bar");
       }
       else
          skipSave = true;                        
    }

    if(!skipSave)
       mail.Save();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried both: main thread and secondary threads and fails in both. Sadly this is not my scenario, I wrote that example to show where it fails but the values I have to set could be anything, so there are more than two options. But again, thanks for answering.